# Debugging Valgrind in C

Tags: c, valgrind

I am still learning valgrind and c. How do I eliminate "Invalid free()"?

error:

```
==31415== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==31415==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31415==    by 0x400EE1: songDelete (song.c:44)
==31415==    by 0x400B70: main (songtest.c:117)
==31415==  Address 0x51fd9f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 14 free'd
==31415==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31415==    by 0x400EE1: songDelete (song.c:44)
==31415==    by 0x400AD3: main (songtest.c:105)
.......
```

code:

```
void songDelete(song *s)
{
    if(s == NULL){
        return;
    }

    //artist
    free(s->artist) ;
    //title
    free(s->title) ;
    //time
    if(NULL != s->lastPlayed)
        mtimeDelete(s->lastPlayed) ;
    //song
    free(s) ;
    s = NULL;
}
```

I added `free(s);` and `s=NULL;` and `if(s == NULL)..`

struct:

```
typedef struct song_{
    char *artist;
    char *title;
    mtime *lastPlayed;
}song;
```

So I am not quite sure how I would fix this problem?

Comment: What's on your line 44 in song.c? That's where the problem is.

Comment: @HuaTham At line 44 is `free(s->artist);` Any suggestion?

Comment: Your song struct is relevant. Presumably artist is something that may not be allocated?

Comment: `s = NULL;` is not changed original.

Comment: @DanFego I added the struct code, from song.h

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so I just remove that code then?

Comment: You didn't show us the allocation, but if you used c++ code allocation like `new` (instead of c-code allocation like `malloc`) then you need to use `delete` instead of `free`.  Alternatively, note that setting `*s=NULL` only changes `s` inside your routine, and when you return, the parent function still has `*s` equal the address that you just freed and you may not handle that right and end up double-freeing.

Comment: _then_ It is checked whether the call with the intention of was changed to NULL by releasing already in the same pointer.

Comment: @JohnH I added allocation, `*songCopy`

Comment: @guy201485 - `strdup` might be helpful to you. It consolidates some of what you are doing. See [strdup - duplicate a string](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html). Also, since `mtime` is fixed size, you might consider including it directly (rather than a pointer to it). It also keeps you out of the memory manager.

Comment: need to see the code/loop in main() that is calling songDelete.

Comment: @JohnH Image: http://gyazo.com/c7fc0a35a73f0125f3923bd708a11910.png Hope that helps. It's a main function.

Comment: @JohnH in Main.c, `songDelete(song1);` There is no for loop for songDelete, check the image I provided in previous comment.

Comment: Just to be sure you understand why you have this error:  the valgrind report is saying that on line 117, you are freeing memory you already freed on line 105 (in songtest.c).  I saw it myself in your original code - you are deleting it twice.  And your songDelete routine can't protect against it the way it is written in the original.

Comment: I'm not at all shameless in up ticking this just because the OP is exhibiting a *desire* to utilize and understand Valgrind. Its a pretty sad thing that the rarity of that fact is what triggers said-generosity, but none the less, hats off!, @guy201485.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main, call `songDelete( &song1 );`  and change songDelete to:

```
void songDelete(song **s)
{
  if(*s == NULL){
      return;
  }

  //artist
  free((*s)->artist) ;
  //title
  free((*s)->title) ;
  //time
  if(NULL != (*s)->lastPlayed)
      mtimeDelete((*s)->lastPlayed) ;
  //song
  free(*s) ;
  *s = NULL;
}
```

This will allow you to actually cause the variable in `main`, such as `song1` to actually be set to NULL after freeing it.

Comment: When I compile the code, it gave me few errors: `error: conflicting types for 'songDelete'
 void songDelete(song **s)` and few more `error: request for member 'artist' in something not a structure or union
     free(*s->artist) ;
`

Comment: You will also need to change the prototype for songDelete higher up in your code to be something like: `void songDelete(song **);`

Comment: Okay, I did that, got this: `song.c:44:12: error: request for member 'artist' in something not a structure or union
     free(*s->artist) ;` along with title and lastplayed.

Comment: sorry, added some parentheses to correct operator precedence.